# How to exclude an amount?

Tags: regex, vba

I have two strings with the same amount:

```
Price $22.00
Price Max=$22.00
```

Can someone please advise how I can modify this regex pattern to make sure that the price with a "Max" in front of it will be ignored?

```
(?:MAX=|MAX=\s)[$]?[0-9]{0,2}?[,]?[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{0,2}
```

Comment: which language are you trying to code ?

Comment: @ArchitGoyal it's a VBA

Comment: Why not capture the price after [`Price:`? `Price\s*\$?(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)`](https://regex101.com/r/qCEfgQ/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That word isn't always over there. The only constant is the "Max=".

Comment: And you want to extract only the price that is not preceded with `Max=`?

Comment: What are you wanting as your output for these two examples. Completely 100% not clear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's correct

Comment: @JNevill I apologize. I want to exclude all prices/amounts that have "Max=" in front of them.

Comment: But what does that mean "Exclude" and what you are wanting as your output? The full string `"Price $22.00"` or `$22.00` or something else. Is this being done in a loop or are these two rows of data sitting in the same variable?

Comment: @JNevill This might be sitting in the same string. I'm only interested in the amount ($22.00) If the amount doesn't have a "Max= " in front of it.

Comment: @hod Gotcha. That makes sense then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may capture the `MAX=` into an *optional* capturing group and check if it matched when all matches are found. Only grab the value if the Group 1 did not match:

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "(MAX=\s*)?\$\d[\d.,]*"
Dim regEx As Object
Dim ms As Object, m As Object

Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regEx.Global = True
regEx.Pattern = strPattern
Dim t As String
t = "Price $24.00    Price Max=$22.00 "

Set ms = regEx.Execute(t)
For Each m In ms
  If Len(m.SubMatches(0)) = 0 Then
     Debug.Print m.value
  End If
Next
```

The `(MAX=\s*)?\$\d[\d.,]*` pattern matches `MAX=` and 0+ whitespaces into an optional group, it matches 1 or 0 times. `\$\d[\d.,]*` will match a digit and any 0+ digits, commas and dots. `If Len(m.SubMatches(0)) = 0 Then` will check if Group 1 is not empty, and if yes, the match is valid.

Comment: I had to play with regex.com to actually understand what you and @AhmedAbdelhameed are talking about... I wasn't sure what "Group 1" is for example, but now it makes sense :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it could be to match what you don't want and to capture what you do want in a capturing group using an alternation:

[`Max=\s*\$[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|(\$[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/wrYuRO/2)

Comment: Nice workaround. Based on the OP's pattern, I think it should be `Max=\s*...` though. It's also worth mentioning that `SubMatches(1)` should be used to access the desired match (in the group) in case the OP isn't familiar with that.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Gotcha - `Submatches(0)`.

Comment: Yep, sorry I meant `SubMatches(0)`.